# Left join  проблемы с DefaultIfEmpty() ошибка "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Добрый день. Cтолкнулся с такой проблемой, у меня есть две таблицы Product и OrderDetail необходимо сделать Left Join этих таблиц. Вот запрос

```
from p in _unitOfWork.Products.All()
    join od in
        (_unitOfWork.OrderDetails.All()
                    .GroupBy(od => new { od.ProductId })
                    .Select(od => new { od.Key.ProductId,
                                        sum = (int?)od.Sum(it => it.Quantity)}))
    on p.Id equals od.ProductId into res
from g in res.DefaultIfEmpty()
    orderby g.sum descending
select new { p, sum = g.sum != null ? g.sum : 0 };
```

Появляется ошибка

> "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Если делаю обычный JOIN таблиц и удаляю из запроса DefaultIfEmpty(), то ошибки нет вот запрос:

```
from p in _unitOfWork.Products.All()
    join od in
        (_unitOfWork.OrderDetails.All()
                    .GroupBy(od => new { od.ProductId })
                    .Select(od => new { od.Key.ProductId,
                                        sum = (int?)od.Sum(it => it.Quantity)}))
    on p.Id equals od.ProductId 
orderby od.sum descending
select new { p, sum = od };
```

Скорее всего он не может найти поле sum. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Comment: А почему так сложно? `.GroupBy(od => new { od.ProductId })` — достаточно просто `.GroupBy(od => od.ProductId)`. И что такое `.All()`?

Comment: функция All возвращает все записи из таблицы

Comment: вот правильный запрос:

from p in _unitOfWork.Products.All()
                     join od in
                         (_unitOfWork.OrderDetails.All()
                             .GroupBy(od => new { od.ProductId })
                             .Select(od => new Temp { ProductId = od.Key.ProductId, SumOrder = (int?)od.Sum(it => it.Quantity) }))
                         on p.Id equals od.ProductId into res
                     from g in res.DefaultIfEmpty(new Temp())
                     orderby g.SumOrder descending
                     select new { p, g.SumOrder };

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, проблема в

```
from g in res.DefaultIfEmpty()
    orderby g.sum descending
select new { p, sum = g.sum != null ? g.sum : 0 };
```

Если `res` пуста, то единственное значение `g` — `null`, и первое из трёх обращений к `g.sum` выбросит исключение.

Comment: в res 100% есть данные проверял

Comment: @Vladimirr: Тогда посмотрите уж в исключение — на каком объекте оно происходит? Чтобы исключить момент телепатии.

Comment: Большое спасибо, вот в чем проблема была http://screencast.com/t/TNUaH4c5hlP , когда обращался к g.sum его просто не было и вылетало исключение.

Comment: @Vladimirr: Ага, вот и отлично. Чините!